# css removed in epi-server issue - correct to use CDATA?

Tags: css, episerver

While having this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="externalsite.com/style.css" />
```

EPi-Server removes this above code when saving.

When having this code:

```
<![CDATA[
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="externalsite.com/style.css" />
//]]>
```

it seems to work.

**Is this a "correct" way of doing this** (to use CDATA) ?

**UPDATE**
It didn't actually work. It was left in code, but the css is not applied ):

**UPDATE2**
In case someone stumples on this issue. use jQuery and add css to head-element (within a document ready).

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://externalsite.com/style.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: Why are you saving a stylesheet reference in EPiServer Edit Mode?

Comment: I deliverad a code that client could put anywhere on his site. In this code it's a stylesheet reference. I have no option of changing in my clients framework - and my client just put it in "edit mode". I guess styles-sheets should be stored in a certain structure on EPI Server, but that's way beyong my privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CDATA sections are used to exempt data from being parsed as HTML, so you would just be turning the code to visible content.

Comment: I figured that out after a while... therefore I used jQuery instead... :-) Thanks for ur answer!